# Make Ardent in Laravel not requiring new password on save

Tags: php, laravel-4, ardent

I'm doing user editing facility for my admin panel. I want to ignore empty password on update, but not on create.

I have following validation rules for User model:

```
public static $rules = array(
    'login'                 => 'required|max:255|alpha_dash|unique',
    'displayname'           => 'required|max:255|unique',
    'email'                 => 'required|email|max:255|unique',
    'password'              => 'required|confirmed',
    'password_confirmation' => 'required',
);
```

But it doesn't let me update user model when I don't pass password to it. It just complains about not having a password.

How to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this in your controller:

```
if ($user->exists)
{
    $user::$rules['password'] = (Input::get('password')) ? 'required|confirmed' : '';
    $user::$rules['password_confirmation'] = (Input::get('password')) ? 'required' : '';
}

$user->save();
```

Comment: But when I somehow want to change the password, it doesn't need confirmation then. It is undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

That's something people are still thinking about. But usually create rules and update rules will be different.

```
public static $create_rules = array(
    'login'                 => 'required|max:255|alpha_dash|unique',
    'displayname'           => 'required|max:255|unique',
    'email'                 => 'required|email|max:255|unique',
    'password'              => 'required|confirmed',
    'password_confirmation' => 'required',
);

public static $update_rules = array(
    'login'                 => 'required|max:255|alpha_dash|unique',
    'displayname'           => 'required|max:255|unique',
    'email'                 => 'required|email|max:255|unique',
);
```

Then in your validation code, you can

```
if ( ! $this->exists || Input::get('password'))
{
   $validation_rules = static::$create_rules;
}
else
{
   $validation_rules = static::$update_rules;
}
```

Comment: But when I somehow want to change the password, it doesn't need confirmation then. It is undesirable.

Comment: The code was just to gave you some thoughts about it. You can check if there's a password filled in the input, then you can just use the create rules again. It all depends on how you'll change your user password. Mine is a form with 2 inputs only. No other user data involved. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to consolidate this behavior to the model itself (so it doesn't matter where it's being created/saved from) you can utilize Ardent's `beforeValidate` function to change the rules before validating:

`public function beforeValidate()
{
    if(isset($this->id))
    {
        self::$rules['password'] = 'confirmed';
        self::$rules['password_confirmation'] = '';
    }
}`

You would just add code like that anywhere in the model in question.